# Intellij Idea 15 Gradle project import Junit compile errors

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, junit

I am having a issue with simple project's junit in Intellij Idea.

Gradle (2.10) can run the junits from command line.
Import the project to Intellij Idea 15.0.3, try to run the JUnit in intellij it throws compile errors as if the junit is not on the classpath.
Error:(1, 17) java: package org.junit does not exist

checked the project structure the junit lib is there, also tried the other method adivised - create Test in Intellij 'Goto Test > create new Test >' still not much luck.

build.gradle:

```
allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'idea'
    apply plugin: 'java'

    sourceCompatibility = 1.7
    group 'junit.fail'
    version '1.0'

    repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    }
}

subprojects {
    dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':common')
    compile project(':modA')
}
```

settings.gradle

```
rootProject.name = 'junit-fail'
include 'common'
include 'modA'
```

Simple code in module common

junit-fail\common\src\main\java

```
public class ClassA {
    public String getA() {
        return "A";
    }
}
```

junit-fail\common\src\test\java

```
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class ClassATest {
    @Test
    public void testGetA() throws Exception {
        ClassA a = new ClassA();
        assertEquals("A", a.getA());
    }
}
```

modA can have the similar test code.

Answer (score 0):

Able to resolve the issue by moving .gradle from c:\users\ to c:\dev
JDK8 was ok but JDK7 never worked - my home dir is network synced. so that may have been an issue.